# Getting an error when creating Trial orgs from Environment Hub

Tags: winter15, environment-hub, trialforce

I'm getting an error when creating a trialforce demo org from environment hub as of winter 15.

> Creating the new org failed. Please try again later.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

[image: Trialforce Error]

Answer (score 1):

This most often happens when the username is invalid (ie taken).  However, I've tried to have my username be something like blah@test.dev.401 and it wouldn't tell me inside the Environment Hub that Salesforce doesn't recognize this as a valid email address, and therefore not a valid username.  Got the more descriptive error signing up through developer.salesforce.com.  Try using the dev org signup page to see what's going on.  (Also, if My Domain is taken, that'll produce generic error)

Answer (score 0):

Try it again and you should be able to create the new Trialforce ORG. Sometimes the Error stops on it's own and It is mostly not replicable.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, the problem for me was that username wasn't unique. As soon as I updated the username, the org was created successfully